# Find the value of U by the means of superposition

Tags: voltage, current, superposition

[image]

I want to do that by superposition rule.

Firstly i need to short the E source and compute U0 in case of current divider formula?

So i will get u1 which is voltage loss when the voltage source is short
$$ U1=6mA\cdot \frac{2R}{2R+R0}$$
Then in second case i will use only E source.
Now i have to find total current in that circuit which is equal
$$ It=\frac{E}{2R+R0}$$
And then i just compute U2 which is voltage loss when we have our current source open
$$ U2=1mA\cdot 2kOhm$$
And my result is 
$$ U0=U2+U1=5V $$
Am i right?

Comment: Start by correcting U1. There's 2R in parallel with Ro.  Multiply the resulted resistance by J to get the J-part of Uo. Ask then again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With \$E\$ shorted out, you have \$R\$ in parallel with \$2 R\$. The \$J\$ current will divide between these. Select only the portion that goes through \$R_0\$ here and write it down.

Now return \$E\$ and remove (open) \$J\$. Now you have \$E\$ in a series loop containing two \$R\$ resistors and one \$R_0\$ resistor. Again, compute the current through \$R_0\$ here and write it down.

Now sum the two values. What do you get?

---

P.S. It may help a little that I also suggest you look at the direction of the current arrow for \$R_0\$. This may indicate a sign reversal to be thinking about.

Comment: Oh, okay i thought that second resistor is not needed, ten value od my u1 will be 3V. Current when J is open is  4V/4kOhm=1mA and now im calculating voltage loss on R0 which is R0*1mA=2V. Suming all up i get 5V. Am I correct now?

Comment: @c0rv There are two currents. What are you getting as the current through \$R_0\$ when shorting out \$E\$?

Comment: To compute U1 i  need Resistance and I, and value of I Is J? Or i am wrong?

Comment: @c0rv You have enough information to compute the current through \$R_0\$ with the voltage source shorted out. Do you see that fact? Or not?